# Viewpager Tabs Fragment & Normal Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs

I apologize in beforehand for my bad code and bad knowledge. I have just recently started coding in Android and Java

My problem is that I have Navigation Drawer and Tabs. Although if I choose something from the navigation drawer which loads up in a Fragment it doesn't show. Only the tabs are showing.

My plan is that one navigation drawer tab shall have 3 tabs inside and the rest just normal pages without tabs.

MainActivity.java

http://pastebin.com/TV7aWy9c

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="se.themeister.hello.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#009900"
            android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I don't know if that's enough or if more information or code is needed

Answer (score 11):

The problem with your code is that your `ViewPager` with `TabLayout` should be part of the `Fragment`, not part of the `Activity`. And `NavigationDrawer` should just replace one fragment by another in the viewport (i.e. in the container). Now, in your code, you're trying to somehow insert your new `Fragment` into the `ViewPager`.

**[Here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ywa7rbjssyuhrog/MyApplication.zip?dl=0)** a very basic app with Navigation Drawer, one Fragment with Tabs and rest fragments without tabs, which you can use as an example:

[image]

`Activity.xml`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />    
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The code in the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new FragmentWithTabs()).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.fragment_1) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new FragmentWithTabs()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.fragment_2) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new FragmentWithoutTabs()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.fragment_3) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new Fragment()).commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I.e., as you see, I'm replacing fragments in the `FrameLayout` with id `fragmentContainer`.

All logic related to the fragment with tabs, incapsulated in `FragmentWithTabs`:

```
public class FragmentWithTabs extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_with_tabs, container, false);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return new SubFragment(position == 0? Color.BLUE : position == 1? Color.WHITE : Color.RED);
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return position+"";
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 3;
            }
        });

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I hope, it helps

Comment: I have been following the same approach as well but there's one drawback that I am also looking to fix. Ideally `Toolbar` and `TabLayout` should have the same color but using above approach there will be shadow between `TabLayout` and `Toolbar` which is not ideal.